# Is it possible to view any file type within a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to allow my users to upload almost any time of file and be able to view it.  Is there some sort of plugin that will allow any file to be used or some sort of technique that will allow for this?

I was looking for a file viewer frame, but I was unable to find one.  Will I have to convert all of the files?

Comment: You're going to have to put restrictions on the file type somewhere. How would a user view a file created by AutoCAD software, for instance?

Comment: you need to handle each type individually by hand. full-screen sized <img>+<video>, iframe w/dataURL for html files or innerHTML for snips,  textarea for text, beautify for JSON, hex editor for binary...

Comment: What would you do with Postscript?  Run it or display it as text?

Comment: The files that people are uploading are anything from psds to images to videos to docs.  If it is something way out there and rare, I will just have them download it.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/broofa/node-mime is a library used for automatic mime lookups.  Note that your browser won't necessarily know how to display all possible file types without some sort of plugin.

Comment: the file itself has a mime property, type, that's provided by the OS so it won't get out of date or broken with an over-ride like a static list will.

Comment: @dandavis - The mime type provided by the File API is not reliable.  I don't think it even comes from the OS.  A folder named "myFolder.jpg" is reported to have a type of "image/jpeg".  The browser is just using simple file extension mappings to report mime type.

Comment: "The browser is just using simple file extension mappings to report mime type", as opposed to what? how does the script to point to do better?

Comment: The more reliable way to identify MIME types is to read the file header and look for "magic bytes" that are common to files of that type (for some files, it's a bit more complicated then that though).  gilly3 You are correct that the browser simply looks at file extensions.  @dandavis you are correct that the referenced library does the same.

Comment: There's another library called mimemagic that does just that, I believe

Comment: @dandavis - I wouldn't rely on such a script either.  I'd do something like what Ray suggests.

Comment: It's pretty trivial to do this server side.  Many libraries already exist (such as mimemagic).  It's a bit more challenging client-side, but possible.

Comment: let's step back for a second and realize that we're spending more time on worrying about potential mis-configurations than we are talking about accomplishing the display of correctly-configured files... it's silly to rip apart binary or send user data to server land when the vast majority of files people will want to view work fine based on ext, and we got larger issues...

Comment: The point being that if the mime-type is correct, the browser knows how display most relevant file types already.  I think we might be overthinking it... lol

Answer (score 0):

Your browser itself is the plugin that knows how to display most file types.  Load the uploaded file into an `<iframe>` and let the browser display it.  That way you can display any type of file that the browser knows how to display.

Comment: that would be a crummy UX for images and prevent lots of displayable content like application/json. many types would accidentally download instead of showing up. i wish it were so simple to do well...